# Convert a Google Doc to more beautiful format, but still editable

Tags: pdf, word-processor

I'd like to make this [Google Doc I've created](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k6auz_44yFZJ1Sd8uGMSoDUSjeqYSprX3JKCjMvxMGc/edit?usp=sharing) into some kind of document that most everyone can download and easily fill out on their computer, but that lends itself to a more attractive aesthetic, because while the Google Doc is easy to use, it's not very inspiring. Is pdf a better way? Pdf's can be made more attractive, but I'd be concerned that most people wouldn't know how to edit a pdf directly. Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!
Phil